# Showing Native and Web in the same page of the Worklight apps

Tags: native, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

All,

We know that WL.NativePage.Show() API can be used to show the native page from a Worklight hybrid app. But one of our customers had asked if we can show the Native page in half with the  Web page in the same HTML page. For example, We would like to show the map or any form that are developed in native code partially in the same HTML page [half native code + half web based code]. So I don't think we can achieve this with WL.NativePage.Show() API. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains how to do it with a native WebView on top of WL application, but technically it can be any native component.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_06_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf

Comment: the WebViewOverlay concept is used to show the mobile web pages  on to the WL hybrid app. I am not too sure if we can call native pages  which are developed in Android Java or Objective C using the WebViewOverlay approach that you have suggested above.

Comment: page is activity/view controller. You can navigate between pages by using WL.NativePage API. WebViewOverlay tutorial explain how to put native controls on top of existing hybrid web app, not the whole page.